# Prevent Voice Memos from ending up on iPhone when connecting to iTunes

Tags: iphone, voice-memo

I deleted Voice Memos from my iPhone. However, after I connected it to my laptop and open iTunes, it just restored all the Voice Memos again. How do I get rid of this?

I just need all notes on my laptop, but not on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that iTunes is not automatically syncing your iPhone when the latter is connected to your computer. In the iTunes Menu bar, go to iTunes → Preferences... and in the preferences window that opens click on the **Devices** tab. Now check **Prevent iPods, iPhones and iPads from syncing automatically** option.

[image]

Also, if you do have to sync your iPhone with your iTunes library, make sure Voice Memos are not selected.

[image]